# help setting environment variables

Tags: bash, environment-variables

```
    Checking for required M4 macros...
  libtool.m4 not found
  glib-gettext.m4 not found
  intltool.m4 not found
  pkg.m4 not found
***Error***: some autoconf macros required to build Package
  were not found in your aclocal path, or some forbidden
  macros were found.  Perhaps you need to adjust your
  ACLOCAL_FLAGS?
```

I've noticed most variables are paths and error output above indicates that aclocal requires one as well. If that is the case : what is aclocal, how can I find it(will apt-file search work?), and what is meant by flag anyway?

Comment: Thanks Janos. I appreciate the edit. That's what I was trying to do LOL. and thank you for bringing that other question to my attention Fac

Comment: I should have been more specific with my question. the other question probably would have popped up.

Comment: I found that question by doing a google search for "libtool.m4 not found" ...

Comment: Thanks again. I really appreciate all the help I've gotten on this site.